# What does java.exe do in the bin directory?

Tags: java

There's a file called `java.exe` somewhere in Java's program directory on Windows.

- What does it do? Is it the entrance of the JVM?
- How can I get its source code?

Comment: What do you mean by "what does it do"? Why is it in *that* directory? What is the *purpose* of it? How does it *work*? Anyway, the source is here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/bin

Comment: What java.exe does is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: It feels kinda good to improve a zero-score post and then see an upvote on it.

Comment: I want to know how does it work。

Answer (score 2):

java.exe and javaw.exe are the two "entrances of the JVM" (in your words). The difference between them is that java.exe brings up a terminal window (e.g. Console Host) to use for `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err`, while javaw.exe doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

And you could probably get source code on http://openjdk.java.net/

It would be a slightly different thing but not by much.